# Tkinter memory leak when updating label

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, label

I m doing a big tkinter application, simply I query modbus datas and if some values are bad, I show it on the tkinter window.

My issue is here : I m querying modbus values every 2 minutes so I made a Label called "StateLabel" that displays a timer made by myself that is updated every seconds (the label will be 120, 119, ... 1, 'query datas', 120 ... again and again).

Unfortunately, I found a memory leak on this line :( when I m not updating the label, no memory leak and when I m updating there is a memory leak.

Here's part of my code that causes problem (sorry I cannot show all my code for privacy reason)

Here is the function that update my label :

```
def updateLabel(StateLabel) :
    global start
    global update

    if(update) : #if we need to update state label
        StateLabel['text'] = "--- Waiting " + str(abs(int((time.time_ns() - start)/1000000000)-120)) + " seconds for new values ---" #update state label

    return
```

this function is called in another function and this other function is pointed by a thread that is launched until the user close the application.

I was thinking maybe when a thread is launched, it creates an instance of Label with same properties than the "real one", since the thread is launched again and again maybe it creates Label over and over ?

If you have any idea of why my memory is leaking, it will be really useful. Thank you for your help !

To resolve the problem, i tried lots of things...

1. try StateLabel.destroy() and create a brand new label (not usefull, slower, not real beautiful, and does not resolve the memory leak)
2. try StateLabel.configure(...) (does not resolve memory leak)
3. try StateLabel['text'] as a dictionary (doesnot resolve memory leak)

I also tried a memory profiler to see clearly what s happening and it's not really clear but I m sure that this line

```
StateLabel['text'] = "--- Waiting " + str(abs(int((time.time_ns() - start)/1000000000)-120)) + " seconds for new values ---" #update state label
```

cause the problem...

EDIT :

here s a complete code that represent my problem I have a instance that create a thread and this thread call a function and that function call the update function that updates the label, but the ram is getting bigger and bigger :/

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import threading
import time


class Window(Tk) :
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("250x250")
        self.title("test")


        self.label = Label(self, text="a")
        self.label.pack()

        self.threadlauncher()

    def threadlauncher(self, *args) :
        thread = threading.Thread(target=main, args=[self.label], daemon=True)

        if(not thread.is_alive()) :
            thread.start()
    
        self.after(500, self.threadlauncher)


def main(label, *args) :
        update(label)
    
def update(label, *args) :
    label['text']="updated label " + str(time.time_ns())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Window()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't call `self.after(...)` inside `threadlauncher()` and use `while` loop with `time.sleep(...)` inside `main()`.

Comment: I suggest you remove the use of threads. If all you're doing is updating a label, a thread adds too much overhead. You definitely don't need to be creating a new thread twice a second.